# Deepin desktop environment installation error

Tags: apt, package-management

I use ubuntu 20.04 and i want to download the deepin desktop environment.
I wrote at google how to get this desktop environment and i have to open the terminal and write:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt install ubuntudde-dde ubuntudde-dde-extras.

When i write the third command it says: **Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)**
What should i do?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` ?

Comment: I did it and it says: : Sub-procces /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste full error output to it.

Comment: I wrote the full error. When i wrote sudo apt fix --broken... It also says:Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score -1):

You might want to reconfigure the package database, as it seems broken.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: i did it. what should i do now?

Comment: Try reinstalling the program now.

Comment: it says again: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Comment: what if you run apt --fix-broken install

Comment: i did it and it says: Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb : Sub-procces /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I guess you need to remove troubling package 
or, Simply re-configure the apt package database and force install it using 
dpkg --force-all -i PackageName

Comment: i don't know a lot of things so can you write me what i have to write in the console?